# Отображение для авторизованных и не авторизованных php

Tags: php, авторизация, безопасность

Суть вопроса такова:
как правильно разграничивать доступ для авторизованных и не авторизованных пользователей. Авторизация на основе куке реализованная.
Возможность проверить авторизован пользователь или нет имеется.
Сейчас делаю так:

1. Проверяю на каждой странице которая предназначена только для авторизованных пользователей путем запроса в БД каждый раз когда страница открывается авторизован пользователь или нет (в куках данные если есть проверяю их соответствие в БД если все ОК то страница показывается если нет то редирект на страницу с логином). Правильно ли это? Или как-то по-другому нормальные прогеры делают? Точно ли нужно каждый раз стучать в БД?
2. Если пользователь не авторизован, то нужно показывать ссылку на страницу с логином или регистрацию, а если он авторизован то писать его имя + привет и показывать ссылки на другие страницы которые доступны для авторизованных. Т.Е. если авторизован, то ссылки видно, если нет, то и ссылок нет.. Тут вообще какой принцип? Как это реализовывают люди?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2й вариант + постоянно стучать в бд